# SQLite support in SORM?

Tags: scala, orm, sorm

I was looking for a lightweight Hibernate alternative for a small Scala project and SORM looks very promising. Currently I use SQLite, but according to the [official website](http://sorm-framework.org/SORM-vs-Slick.html) it is not supported. So my question is are there any plans to add SQLite support in SORM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently it is a very low priority, since SORM already provides support for two other embedded databases: H2 and HSQLDB. Since H2 is a pure JVM one it is the recommended choice.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem there are [not any such plans](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/sorm/issues/search?q=sqlite) at the moment.